# CSS hover effect on a table doesn't apply tbody and tr hover effects when the cursor is between 2 cells

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm using the below HTML and CSS code to create a table with grouped rows where both the group and the row react to a hover event:

```css
.c-table-display {
  border-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  width: 100%;
}

.c-table-display__row-odd {
  background-color: #f3f7fc;
  color: #263340;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.c-table-display__row-odd>td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.c-table-display__row-even {
  background-color: #deecf8;
  color: #263340;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.c-table-display__row-even>td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.c-table-display__body--highlightable:hover tr {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #E3EBDE;
}

tr.c-table-display__row--highlightable:hover {
  background: #FFE56F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.c-table-display__body--highlightable:hover td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.c-table-display__row--highlightabe:hover td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.c-table-display__cell--icon {
  text-align: center;
}

.c-table-display__cell--icon>img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table class="u-width-full c-table-display">
  <tbody class="c-table-display__body c-table-display__body--highlightable">
    <tr class="c-table-display__row-odd c-table-display__row c-table-display__row--highlightable js-machine-param-row" machinerowid="17" parameterrowid="102">
      <td>'test</td>
      <td title="unique">
        unique
      </td>
      <td title="">

      </td>
      <td title="">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c-table-display__row-even c-table-display__row c-table-display__row--highlightable js-machine-param-row" machinerowid="17" parameterrowid="113">
      <td title="keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykey">
        keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeyke...
      </td>
      <td title="valuevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevalueva">
        valuevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevalue...
      </td>
      <td title="keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykey">
        keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeyke...
      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem I have is that if I hover over the space RIGHT between 2 cells, neither the row nor the group gets the hover effect. How can I fix this, preferably without removing the border-spacing? I'd rather not use Javascript since we were using a Javascript implementation before that caused issues with hover effects lingering.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.c-table-display {
  //border-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  width: 100%;
}

.c-table-display__row-odd {
  background-color: #f3f7fc;
  color: #263340;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.c-table-display__row-odd>td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.c-table-display__row-even {
  background-color: #deecf8;
  color: #263340;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.c-table-display__row-even>td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.c-table-display__body--highlightable:hover tr {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #E3EBDE;
}

tr.c-table-display__row--highlightable:hover {
  background: #FFE56F;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.c-table-display__body--highlightable:hover td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.c-table-display__row--highlightabe:hover td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.c-table-display__cell--icon {
  text-align: center;
}

.c-table-display__cell--icon>img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="u-width-full c-table-display">
  <tbody class="c-table-display__body c-table-display__body--highlightable">
    <tr class="c-table-display__row-odd c-table-display__row c-table-display__row--highlightable js-machine-param-row change" machinerowid="17" parameterrowid="102">
      <td>'test</td>
      <td title="unique">
        unique
      </td>
      <td title="">

      </td>
      <td title="">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c-table-display__row-even c-table-display__row c-table-display__row--highlightable js-machine-param-row" machinerowid="17" parameterrowid="113">
      <td title="keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykey">
        keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeyke...
      </td>
      <td title="valuevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevalueva">
        valuevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevaluevalue...
      </td>
      <td title="keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykey">
        keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeyke...
      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
      <td class="c-table-display__cell c-table-display__cell--icon">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

you can remove and cell spacing and add `border` for spacing on `td` now just set border top bottom properties for first and last child and you are good to go.

Ping me if you have any query.